# How to return different tags with different values for the same metric using telegraf input exec

Tags: prometheus, grafana, telegraf

Using this example

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'example,tag1=a,tag2=b i=42i,j=43i,k=44i'
```

and the following config

```
[[inputs.exec]]
commands = ["sh /tmp/test.sh"]
timeout = "5s"
data_format = "influx"
```

Yields a result like the following

```
# HELP job_status_i Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE job_status_i untyped
job_status_i{tag1="a",tag2="b"} 42
# HELP job_status_j Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE job_status_j untyped
job_status_j{tag1="a",tag2="b"} 43
# HELP job_status_k Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE job_status_k untyped
job_status_k{tag1="a",tag2="b"} 44
```

Instead what I want to do is have one metric called 'job_status' with a tag each (a,b,c) with different values. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `a tag each` ? Only one tag name with a different value each ?